# how to store and retrieve a char* from a string?

Tags: c++, stl

`const char *RecBuffer, int *packetLength` point to the data and the size

```
    string packet(RecBuffer,*packetLength);//store here
     ...do some stuff
    RecBuffer = packet.c_str();//retrieve it later
```

now what is happening is that my Recbuffer contains lots of floats, and ints packet together which I receive as a UDP packet. But when I store and retrieve it from the string it contains garbage.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Are the floats in text or binary representation? Does "packet" continue to live on for the same time as RecBuffer?

Comment: If your `Recbuffer` contains arbitrary data, you should use `vector<char>` instead of `string`.

Comment: Do you want to work with the values or the addresses? Because I cannot see really what you are up to... What is the signature of "packet"?

Comment: `std::string` should be used for strings, it doesn't sound like your data is a string.

Answer (score 7):

I suspect the `std::string` instance named `packet` is being destructed, or modified, before `RecBuffer` is being used, meaning `RecBuffer` is a dangling pointer. You need to copy the content of `packet` rather than store a reference to an internal member of it. Instead of dynamically allocating a `char*` suggest using a [`std::vector<char>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) (as commented by Bartek) instead:

```
std::vector<char> RecBuffer(packet.begin(), packet.end());
```

Use `&RecBuffer[0]` (or `RecBuffer.data()` if available, introduced in c++11) to access the internal array.

Answer (score 1):

**Use memcpy:**

```
RecBuffer[packet.size()]=0;
memcpy(RecBuffer, packet.c_str(), packet.size());
```